# Definition of boolean_expression in jq

Tags: jq

According to the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#select(boolean_expression)) `select` needs a parameter `boolean_expression`.
I always wonder what exactly is meant by this in `jq`.
To take full advantage of the `select` filter, it would be nice to have a clear definition.

Can someone give this missing precise definition?

The following collection of unusual examples looks a bit strange and counterintuitive to me:

`jq -n '1,2 | select(null)'`  outputs nothing

`jq -n '1,2 | select(empty)'`  outputs nothing

`jq -n '1,2 | select(42)'`  outputs `1 2`

`jq -n '1,2 | select(-1.23)'`  outputs `1 2`

`jq -n '1,2 | select({a:"strange"})'`  outputs `1 2`

`jq -n '1,0,-1,null,false,42 | select(.)'`  outputs `1 0 -1 42`

It seems to me that everything that is not `false` and not `null` is considered `true`.

In the examples, the constants are to understand as placeholders for the result of an arbitrary expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `null` and `false` are indeed considered falsy, other values as truthy. This notion is (somewhat unfortunately) explained in the [if-then-else](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else) section of the manual.

Therefore `jq -n '1,2 | select(null)'` will produce nothing, as would `jq -n '1,2 | select(false)'`

In the case of `jq -n '1,2 | select(empty)'`, the `empty` just eats up all the results, so there is nothing to output.

All other cases are truthy, therefore the input is propagated.

Note that none of your examples considers the actual input for evaluation. All `select`s have a constant argument.

To filter based on the input, the argument of `select` has to somehow process it (as opposed to constants which simply ignore it), e.g. `jq -n '1,2 | select(.%2 == 0)'` outputs just `2`.

Comment: Ah, at the `if-then-else` section the definition of `boolean_expression` is "hidden" ... thank you very much!

Comment: I added one example that considers the input